# How to create click button in pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

how to create click button in pure/native JavaScript without using any html tag and css? This button, when the user click it there's a confirmation box will appear then, when the user click the Ok option, there's a popup window will appear.

I have already code in popup window and confirmation box. Here:

```
 if (confirm("Go?") == true) {
            popupWindow = window.open('/filename.htm', "name", windowFeatures);
            popupWindow.focus();
            } else {
            test1= "";
            }
```

I want to display the click button under of:

```
<div class="activityHeaderPanel">
```

But, I don't have an access or privilege to change or edit the entire html.

Please help me. I'm not really a programmer. Thank you.

Comment: You will need HTML if you want to render something like  button in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native DOM API to create document nodes and attach events, using pure Javascript and no HTML.

```
var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
myDiv.className = 'activityHeaderPanel';
myDiv.onclick = function(){
    if(confirm //...
}
```

To attach the div you created to the existing document you need to find its parent node and use appendChild:

```
//this will depend on your particular use case. For example, if the parent element is a
// <div id="theParent">

var parentNode = document.getElementById('theParent');
parentNode.appendChild(myDiv);
```

Comment: what do you mean by this ç?

Comment: No button displayed, please see this link http://jsfiddle.net/k873b/ if the syntax is correct

Comment: Opening the browser developer tools (F12) will tell you that there is a syntax error (you are missing a closing } in the function. As for the div not displaying, the code in the JSfiddle is just for creating the div. for example, `document.body.appendChild(myDiv)` would put the div at the end of the document (you might need to add some css to make the div visible)

Comment: Can you give me the right code? Sorry, I'm stupid in programming

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = document.getElementByClass("activityHeaderPanel");

function whatClicked(evt) {
    alert(evt.target.id);
}

test.addEventListener("click", whatClicked, false);
```

Comment: how do I connect that into my current confirmation code?